# Error in flutter gradle after adding firebase messaging

Tags: firebase, gradle, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter

A have the following error and searched a lot to solve it, but can't get hold of what versions to use and what to do.

> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.2.0,16.2.0]], but resolves to 15.1.0.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what libraries you're using.

Answer (score 1):

remove

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

from your **app gradle**

and if someone is facing error like

> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.0.1) classpath

then

under your project level gradle file

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

add above lines to bottom of **Project level gradle file**